# How to randomize C# Dictionary item when iterating through a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I want to iterate this dictionary randomly while iterating through a foreach loop:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> listOfDudes = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
        { "zhehan", new List<string>(){"blah blah blah", "WATER"} },
        { "zhixin", new List<string>(){"blah blah blah", "EARTH"} },
        { "taeyung", new List<string>(){"blah blah blah", "MOON"} },
        { "vasily", new List<string>(){"blah blah blah", "WIND"} },
        { "achraf", new List<string>(){"blah blah blah", "DENDRO"} },
        { "zehven", new List<string>(){"blah blah blah", "CELESTIAL"} }
    };
```

through this foreach loop:

```
foreach(var i in listOfDudes) {
     string name = i.Key;
     CreateDudeList(name, i.Value[0], i.Value[1]);
}
```

CreateDudeList() is a function that instantiates prefabs but that's not relevant to this question.

What I want to do is iterate randomly through the dictionary, so that `var i` will take KeyValuePair in random than in sequential order.

I'm confused about how to iterate randomly through this Dictionary with a foreach. Thank you for any answers.

Comment: You could extract the keys, shuffle them, then iterate through the keys in the shuffled order to look up the data.

Comment: I think you understand this already, but it's worth mentioning that Dictionaries are already unordered by definition. That you see any kind of sequential order is a convenience for performance and code maintenance rather than part of any contract for the type.

Answer (score 2):

One simple method:

```
var random = new Random();
foreach (var i in listOfDudes.OrderBy(_ => random.Next())
{
     string name = i.Key;
     CreateDudeList(name, i.Value[0], i.Value[1]);
}
```

`Random.Next()` returns a random integer, so this should order the KeyValuePairs randomly.

Comment: For Unity specific you can use [`Random.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html)

Comment: This approach has multiple issues. For the most serious one see Eric Lippert's comment under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456788/5114784) answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can shuffle the keys of your list and then iterate through those:

```
List<string> shuffledKeys = listOfDudes.Keys.ToList();
Random rng = new Random();
int n = shuffledKeys.Count;
while (n > 1) {
    n--;
    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
    string value = shuffledKeys[k];
    shuffledKeys[k] = shuffledKeys[n];
    shuffledKeys[n] = value;
}

foreach (var key in shuffledKeys) {
    string name = key;
    CreateDudeList(name, listOfDudes[key][0], listOfDudes[key][1]);
}
```

The list itself will not be shuffled, but you will still iterate through it in a random order.

Comment: If you find an already existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/5114784) on SO please vote for closing the question as a duplicate instead of copy-pasting. And even if you adapt it to a somewhat different question (which is not the case here) it would be more correct to indicate your source of inspiration.